# Что использовать для генерации xls, в PHP (40 000 строк)?

Tags: php, excel, xls

Требуется генерировать прайс лист, порядка 40к строк.
Важно чтобы была возможность группировки строк для создания дерева, поддержка старых версий Excel ( 2003 и выше), скорость и разумное потребление памяти.

Пробовал PHPexcel, выполняет все что нужно, но требует очень много памяти, и работает долго.(9 файлов генерируются около 9 минут)

Пробовал Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer (PEAR), работает быстро и памяти ест 30мб, но нет возможности группировать строки.(Возможно я не смог разобраться? Если подскажете как, будет круто).

Если это важно, php 7.0.27, CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708

Спасибо.

Comment: Найдено на enSO - https://stackoverflow.com/a/35480663/8799283

Comment: Найдено в официальном cookbook - https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/